# Images of matrices with same rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

So I am able to prove that $rank(AA^T)=rank(A^T)=rank(A).$ But from this equality, is it sufficient for me to say that $im(AA^T)\subset im(A)$ ?

I am actually trying to prove that $im(A) = im(AA^T )$

The proof on the textbook is:

Write $v = AA^Tx$ as $v =Ay$ where $y = A^Tx$

If $v$ is in the image of $A$, then $v =Ax$.

If $x = y + z$, where $y$ in the kernel of $A$ and $z$ orthogonal to the kernel of $A$, then $Ax =Az$.

Because $z$ is orthogonal to the kernel of $A$, it is in the image of $A^T$ .

Therefore, $z = A^T u$ and $v =Az = AA^T u$ is in the image of $AA^T$

So $im(A)=im(AA^T)$ proved

But I found this proof a little complicated, so I am trying to prove it in an easier way. So so far I got $rank(AA^T)=rank(A^T)=rank(A)$, and I want to say then $im(AA^T)\subset im(A)$, but is it sufficient enough?

Comment: If  the ranks are equal, yes it is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach would work well.

Suppose $v$ lies in the image of $AA^T$.  Then $v = AA^Tx$ for some $x$. So taking $y = A^Tx$, we see that $v = Ay$ is an element of the image of $A$. So $\text{im}(AA^T) \subset \text{im}(A)$. Now you apply your principle of rank:

$$\dim \text{im}(AA^T) = \text{rank}(AA^T) = \text{rank}(A) = \dim \text{im}(A),$$
so we must have $\text{im}(AA^T) = \text{im}(A)$.